# How do I make this list not break lines when browser size is changed?

Tags: html, css, list

I am trying to optimize my site for mobiles but I can't get this "ul" to get displayed correct for the small devices. This is what the page looks like when the browser is still big enough:

[image: Warcraft list style issue]

Then when the browser is at it's smallest width:

[image]

You can see how the "company" text on one of the list elements breaks the line when it cant fit in the window. I want the text to have an ending with "..." at the end instead. How do I achieve this?

```
<ul>
    <li><b><img class='icongo' src="worker67.png"/>Company:</b> <span style='float:right'>Legendary,Universal,Blizzard E</span></li>
    <li><b><img class='icongo' src="open163.png"/>Story:</b> Legendary’s "Warcraft" is a 3D epic adventure of world-colliding conflict based upon Blizzard Entertainment’s globally-renowned universe. Directed by Duncan Jones ("Moon," "Source Code") and written by Charles Leavitt and Duncan Jones, the film is a Legendary Pictures, Blizzard
```

Read more at http://www.comingsoon.net/movie/warcraft-2016#2AgLG7H8xtKTDjFb.99

current css for the list:

```
ul {
   margin: 0px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 100%;
}
ul li {
   padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Comment: I suggest just decrease **1 or 2 px's** for `font-size` for particular media query(one for mobile/small screens).

Comment: Decrease the font-size depending on what device is used or just overall?

Comment: Can you post the representative HTML and not the PHP?

Comment: I suppose you use `media query` right?

Comment: overflow:scroll or font-size:3vh

Comment: It's not necessary to support device widths smaller than 320px unless you're expecting people to visit your site with their smartwatch.

Comment: I don't know what media query is, sorry

Comment: Ok, not an issue. It's one of the coolest think CSS has. Check this: **[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)**.

Comment: ah okey, I'm loading different style sheets for different min-width and max-width with the link at the top of the document: <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1400px)' href='thevplayer.css' />. But that could save some time, the way media queries work.

Comment: Just demonstrating simple example here: **[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/t39jy3uh/)**. Try **reducing width** in fiddle and observe font's size getting reduced based on width changes.

Comment: ah cool, I like that divy3993. I will go with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css media queries are rules that can be changed when the size of user device changed, for example you can use this query in your case:

```
@media(max-width: 400px) {
    ul li {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}
```

but it isn't the standard way you should read more about [css media querires](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and responsive desgins

Answer (score 1):

use `word-break: break-word;`

```
ul li {
   padding-bottom: 16px;
   word-break: break-word;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ru4ym3fr/)**

note that do not insert `<img/>` tag inside `<b>` tag. as you see in example i moved them.